# Safari changes Date and Time Angular

Tags: angular, safari

I have a site in angular 4 which uses dates, in other browsers like Chrome dates are always displayed correctly, but in Safari if I change the computer time ONLY in Safari date and time change.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center border-r">
    <h4 class="txt-null-mar">arrival<label style="font-size:13px;font-weight: 750;">IDA</label></h4>
    <p class="num-hora">{{infoRodamiento.date | date: 'HH:mm' }}</p>
    <p class="dia-viaje">{{infoRodamiento.date| date: 'EEE d MMM' }} </p>

    <p class="num-hora">{{infoRodamiento.date}}</p>
    <p class="dia-viaje">{{infoRodamiento.date}} </p>
</div>
```

I do some date transformations like:

```
this.datepipe.transform(this.infoRodamiento.date, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: well.what does it change to?

Comment: it depends, if the iphone has the date or time wrong, in safari time changes depending how many hours